# kubernetes: Read a pod's secrets from within the pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

Is there a way to read the secrets of a pod from **within** the pod?

The pod is created with the `default` service account so even if I install `kubectl` I will not be able to perform `get secrets` unless I mess with the default SA (which I want to avoid).

I know the secrets are available in plain text via the `env` command but so are a bunch of other environmental variables.

How can I tell **specifically** which are the ones coming from `secrets`?

(I am **not** using a volume to mount secrets and unfortunately for reasons way beyond the scope of this question, this cannot change)

Answer (score 0):

Which secrets are used as values of environmental variables can be seen in the pod's configuration, including for currently running pods. For more info:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

Comment: yes but how can I get the pod's definition FROM WITHIN THE POD?

Comment: Assuming that the pod's config allowed the automounting of API credentials for a service account (no `automountServiceAccountToken: false`), the `default` SA credential token will be in the pod at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`. The token can be used to authenticate to the apiserver to get pod's config.

Comment: That was a good try but it returns `403` :  `"message": "pods \my-pod-name\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:mynamespace:default\" cannot get resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"mynamespace\"",` . And this makes sense as the `default` service account is not allowed to list any resources

Comment: I used this `curl` request btw: `curl -sSk -H "Authorization: Bearer $KUBE_TOKEN"       https://kubernetes.default:443/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods/$HOSTNAME` where `KUBE_TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)`

Answer (score 0):

Your pod needs to talk to the api server and ask for the pod definition, to be able to find it.

For that, pod's service account (be it `default` or a custom one) needs the appropriate `Role` and `RoleBinding` that allows that service account to read certain kubernetes resources, in this case, the pod definition itself, and probably the `Secret` objects in the namespace, so it can find out the corresponding secret (i.e. if there is an environment variable that is coming from a secret via `envFrom` directive).

The service account token is mounted to the path `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` 
in a pod. Using that token, your process can talk to the Kubernetes api from inside the cluster. You can use any Kubernetes client library in any language, or simply `kubectl`. Then it's a matter of implementing the logic that will find out which secrets are providing which files/variables.

Comment: Yes I wanted to be able to do so using the `default` service account. However this prohibits the pod from listing its own description; which is kind of weird since it has access e.g. to its secrets but no way to list them by a call to the api server.

Comment: Did you create an appropriate Role and RoleBinding for a default ServiceAccount as suggested by @Hanx, it should solve you problem.
Please don't forget to provide feedback on community answers !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Downward API to expose Pod fields to containers: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/

On a related note, if you do not rely on automatically injected env vars for service discovery then you may find it useful to reduce number of env vars in your containers with `enableServiceLinks` set to `false`.

Docs: `kubectl explain deployment.spec.template.spec.enableServiceLinks`

EnableServiceLinks indicates whether information about services should be
injected into pod's environment variables, matching the syntax of Docker
links. Optional: Defaults to true.

Answer (score 0):

As described by community:

**1**. If secrets were mounted as Using Secrets as [Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables) 
You an display all of them from within using information from documentation:

```
 env | grep SECRET
 echo $SECRET_your_key
 echo $SECRET_PASSWORD $SECRET_USERNAME
```

**2**. If you are interested with "[Accessing the API from a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod)"

- you can use [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux), [Directly accessing the REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#directly-accessing-the-rest-api) 
  or directly call api-server f.e.:
- `curl -sSk -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" https://kubernetes.default:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/your_secret`
- `curl -v --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" https://kubernetes.default:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/`

If you got the error like: system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default please refer to:

[RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) 
create  role/rolebinding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: default-role
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-deafult-role
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: default-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
```

Please let me know if it helps.